# Update specific nodes in a tree structure

Tags: javascript, tree

I have been struggeling with how to update specific nodes in a tree structure.
What I have is a tree structure with several thousand of objects, all objects have attributes and an id, the id can appear several times in the tree.
So what I want to do is to update some nodes with a specific id and then use the updated tree, but I cant get my head around how to do it.

Some pseudo code:

```
    basenode = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Basenode',
  children: [{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Child node 1',
    children: [
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Child of child node',
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Child of child node',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Child node 3',
    children: []
  }]
}
```

So for example I would like to update the names of the two nodes with id 1 o that I have the same tree structure but with updated names on the nodes with id 1.

Could anyone give me a push in the right direction with this?

Comment: "*the id can appear several times in the tree*" - then it's not an id. Or are you saying that they are the same object, and it's not a tree?

Comment: "*I would like to update the names of the two nodes with id 1*" - what have you tried? Just traverse the tree (using recursion) and update those nodes where your condition matches.

Comment: Well, it is a form of ID. Its a unique ID for a person, but the person can appear several times in the tree

Comment: Ok, the phrasing "*all objects have […] an id*" was misleading then, it sounded like it was an id for the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function updatePropertyById(id, data, property, value) {
    if (data.id == id) {
        data[property] = value;
    }
    if (data.children !== undefined && data.children.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++) {
             data.children[i] = updatePropertyById(id, data.children[i], property, value);
        }
    }

    return data;
}

updatePropertyById(1, basenode, "name", "New Name");
```

Comment: for (**let** i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++)